# Can someone please identify this literary device

Tags: literary-device

"Mike-schmike." I muttered, preoccupied by the way he'd said "you and I." I liked it more than I should.

This is a line from Stephanie Meyer's Twilight novel (page 25). How would we describe 'Mike-schmike' in terms of a literary device. Is there a special name for the rhyming pejorative here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication

Comment: The literary device is irony; the vector is shm-reduplication.